Need to build a community membership and event/ticketing system
Over the years I have worked a bit with Wordpress, but have been more of a custom code developer. I feel that Wordpress is the right framework for my solution but need help with identifying plugins and confirming my path.
I have been asked by my local community to put together a system for about 300 people in this club where there is a way to register online for membership in this club and pay for membership (let's say $20/year). I believe I would just use the Wordpress user management component but change the standard registration and login pages. I would need to ability for people to change passwords and the forget password functionality. I would also need the ability to add custom fields - e.g., what is your local community ID number. It seems that either editing the standing Wordpress "create account" and "login" functionality is correct either manually or via a plugin. Is this the right path? I would also need to have the ability to accept Paypal payments for the membership.
Additionally the club has events. Think of a ballroom with 15 tables and 10 chairs at each table. They would like this members have the ability to select seats at an event. i.e., I need to create the event, design the seating chart, accept payments for one or more tickets, send tickets, etc. I can see there are lots of different SAAS products, plugins, etc, but I'm not sure which is the right one to use.
I assume with all of this Wordpress would have the ability to view membership data (database) and ticketing data (or externally via the SAAS product).
I know there is a lot there, but looking for plugin pointers and confirmation of my direction.
